# how to constantly update a variable with a touchscreen dragging input event position

Tags: input, touchscreen, godot, gdscript

My game require constant update of a var with a drag gesture postion as my finger is moving on the touch sreen please help as im pretty new to programming.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking for, but a good place to start would be to look at using the InputEventScreenTouch() function to capture the screen press as well as the co-ordinates of the press. To make sure it updates every frame, put all the associated logic in the _process() function.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you touch the screen, Godot interprets that as a mouse motion, so to get the position whenever the user has their finger on the screen you can do:

`func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        gesturePostion = event.position`

Now you have the variable 'gesturePostion' which stores the position of your finger on the screen as a Vector2. Just make sure you've defined 'gesturePostion' as a global variable (you can do that by defining the variable outside any function).